# Facebook access_token exchange requires undocumented parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

According to [Facebook's own documentation on the matter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension), the following request should exchange a short lived access_token for a long lived one:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&amp;           
    client_id={app-id}&amp;
    client_secret={app-secret}&amp;
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

I tried making the following request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    grand_type=fb_exchange_token&
    client_secret=abcd1234&
    client_id=12345678&
    fb_exchange_token=CAA...
```

and got the following response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Missing redirect_uri parameter.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191,
      "fbtrace_id": "abcdefg"
   }
}
```

Why is this parameter required as part of OAuth?

You can even [try the request in the browser](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grand_type=fb_exchange_token&client_secret=1234&client_id=abcd&fb_exchange_token=dsa), same results.

Comment: Works fine for me. What do your app settings look like (especially the Client OAuth Settings)?

Comment: @CBroe even the (invalid) request posted above ('try the request in the browser' link)?

I have Client OAuth Login, Web OAuth Login set to yes, the others set to no

Comment: Yes, with that URL, directly in the browser (after putting in data and access token for one of my apps.) Try specifying a redirect URI in the Client OAuth Settings.